# Referencing a 3rd party DLL when generating code using T4 templates

Tags: c#, code-generation, t4

I'm trying to write a T4 template that needs to log into FB to scrape the docs. To do this i need to reference a 3rd party dll. Can this be done and if so, how?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I assume you mean you want the T4 template to use the DLL when generating code.

`<#@ assembly name="$(SolutionDir)thirdparty.dll" #>`